# TortoiseSvn "Show log" opened from Merge windows indicates "Invalid revision passed to Log()"

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn

Using Tortoise SVN in the Merge window,
When I want to select a list of revisions to merge from, I used the Show Log button and I can click on the checkboxes to pick the revisions I'm interested in.

With version 1.8.2 when the Show Log button opens the "Select revision range" Window, it does not show revisions but the message "Invalid revision passed to Log()"

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

**TortoiseSVN 1.8.2 is outdated.** The real solution is to upgrade your TortoiseSVN 1.8.2 client to the latest build which is now [TortoiseSVN 1.8.11](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html).

This is a known bug in TortoiseSVN that has been already fixed. [See the issue 547](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/issues/detail?id=547) which has status *"Fixed"*. However, there is a report about that this could be reproduced with later versions but I don't see any other reports so far.

Here is the related mailing list thread: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3063637.

Answer (score 3):

In the Merge Windows, add a @ at the end of the "URL to merge from" before clicking on "Show log"

Comment: No, this is not a solution. You should upgrade TortoiseSVN to the latest patch update.

Comment: In business environment you may not have rights to choose the version you use, so workarounds are welcome.